# Call method with strongly typed definition from configuration

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, configuration

maybe title is not correctly describing what I want to achieve, so here is an example:

I have a code where I call this:

```
object.AddProvider<definition, implementation>()
```

method description is:

```
public void AddProvider<TDefinition, TImplementation>()
            where TDefinition: class
            where TImplementation : class, TDefinition, IDataProvider
```

I have configuration where I define 'definition' (interface) and 'implementation'

> "Interface": "MyAssembly.Abstractions.IMongoDataProvider,
>   MyAssembly.Abstractions" "Implementation":
>   "MyAssembly.DataProviders.MongoDataProvider, MyAssembly.DataProviders"

Then I call this to get types from the configuration:

```
var definition = System.Type.GetType(@"{Interface}", true, true);
var implementation = System.Type.GetType(@"{Implementation}", true, true);
```

But I am not able to do this

```
object.AddProvider<definition, implementation>()
```

I don't know how to fulfill method's criteria (what to do between last two examples codes). Can anybody help me please?

Comment: `object.AddProvider<definition, implementation>()` Does it not compile? Or fail at runtime? Or something else?

Comment: It's not compilable - 'definition' is a variable but is used like a type.